# Что такое контекст в java

Tags: java

Что такое контекст в java

Comment: [http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если кратко, то однажды возникла идея о том, что у всего должно быть имя (в виде строки). Чтобы получить доступ к объекту по имени, необходимо иметь некоторый интерфейс, а именно, `Context`. То есть контекст - это интерфейс, который позволяет по данной строке получить объект.
Например:

```
try {
// Create the initial context
Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);

// Look up an object
Object obj = ctx.lookup(name);

// Print it
System.out.println(name + " is bound to: " + obj);

} catch (NamingException e) {
    System.err.println("Problem looking up " + name + ": " + e);
}
```

Подробнее [тут](http://java.sun.com/products/jndi/1.2/javadoc/), с примерами, и пояснениями, зачем это нужно.

---

Ссылка из удалённого второго ответа: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html